# Hosted Exchange and Directory Sync

Tags: exchange-2013, microsoft-forefront

We're about to host Exchange 2013 for some clients of ours. We have a multi-tenant Exchange environment.

We would like to sync passwords between our Exchange Servers on our AD and the clients AD.

What we've come across is Microsoft's Forefront Identity Manager. My question is for those of you who have experience with directory syncing.

Will we be able to do syncing between Exchange 2013 (running on Server 2012R2) with clients domains that are at a 2003 and 2008 domain function level? Are there any caveats or gotchas that we should know about?